# Are rake db:create and rake db:migrate idempotent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rails-migrations

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to figure out if `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate` are idempotent.

In other words, can I run these two commands against my DB (postgres or mysql) repeatedly without causing problems?

The idea is to automate the Rails deployment, and have these commands run every time the Rails app is deployed. I'd like to make sure that it doesn't hork the database somehow.

Any other gotchas around the idempotence of rake db migrations is super appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, they are idempotent and running those two commands should just bring your DB "up-to-date", and once you've running them through to completion, then running them again subsequently should do nothing.

However, a better way to set up a brand new machine is to use

```
rake db:setup
```

`db:setup` just runs these tasks in order:

```
db:create
db:schema:load
db:seed
```

Notice `db:setup` does not run `db:migrate`, and instead simply runs `db:schema:load`. Migrations are only required when you are upgrading an existing DB to a newer version, since they describe the differences between two versions of your schema. But when you're setting up a new DB entirely, you can skip the whole history of migrations and jump to the most recent state of the schema, i.e., load the current schema with `db:schema:load`. And `db:seed` runs your `db/seeds.rb` file for creating initial data, if relevant to your application.

Run `rake -T` to describe all the Rails Rake tasks in detail, or view the ActiveRecord [`databases.rake`](https://github.com/rails/docrails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake) source file to read the code directly.

Comment: Awesome. Did not know about db:setup. Quick follow up. Is rake db:setup idempotent as well?

Comment: I'm not sure offhand whether it would be. If `db:seeds` is re-run, depending on how you structured it, it could potentially create new records each time you run it. But since you write that yourself you could also just check if necessary records already exist and only create them if necessary.

Comment: Also, you can view the source of the Rakefile itself from ActiveRecord to determine exactly what is going on: https://github.com/rails/docrails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake

Comment: `rake db:setup` is not idempotent. As of 3.1.12 it runs `db:schema:load` and  `db:seed`.